# Image doesn't attached properly while sending emails from my android email client app

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail

I was trying to write an Email client to sent emails to my Gmail.And I can successfully authenticate my email account and so send message also.At the other end in my email I got this email message,But when I attach an image while sending email, the receiver side says that the image is not valid any help would appreciated.

**Here is my Email function**

```
public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients, String image) throws Exception {

    // Create a default MimeMessage object.
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    // Set From: header field of the header.
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));

    // Set To: header field of the header.
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(sender));
    // Set Subject: header field
    message.setSubject("Testing Subject");

    // This mail has 2 part, the BODY and the embedded image
    MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

    // first part (the html)
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    String htmlText = "<H1>"+body+"</H1><img src=\"cid:image\">";
    messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");
    // add it
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // second part (the image)
    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    System.out.println( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"1409752026872.jpg");
    DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"1409752026872.jpg");

    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
    messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "image");

    // add image to the multipart
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // put everything together
    message.setContent(multipart);
    // Send message
    Transport.send(message);

    System.out.println("Sent message successfully...."+image);    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What mail reader are you using to display the message?

Try making this change:

```
messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");
```